# Two Cameras need them to face each other

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two cameras in a scene,both following different objects I want to make them face each other ,like split screen but opposite sides,also I don't want to touch the rotation of the camera,any heads up with playing with cameras and split screening would be a great help,thanks!

Comment: **Ques 1** : if two camera is following different objects, does it mean cameras are looking at those "objects"? 
**Ques 2** : if two cameras(camera1 and camera2) is face each other; then camera1 will see camera2 and camera2 will just see camera1. Am I understanding correctly? 
**Ques 3** : If you want a camera to point at something, then how can it be done without rotating it? :/ Parenting it will be a solution I guess but you have to rotate the parent in that case.

Comment: I see only solution with rotating cameras.

Comment: ans1:Yes they are looking at those objects.                                            
ans2:facing each other not as in opposite,like show split screen is ,but this one up and down ,like two people playing on end of the phone,end means where the home button is and one end where the ear speaker is.
ans3:will try the third one and let you know ,thanks!
@jerry :i tried your solution ,it works,but have to do lot of changes,maybe that is the only way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the thing you are looking for

```
// This complete script can be attached to a camera to make it 
// continuously point at another object.

// The target variable shows up as a property in the inspector. 
// Drag another object onto it to make the camera look at it.

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform target;

void Update() {
    // Rotate the camera every frame so it keeps looking at the target 
    transform.LookAt(target);
}
}
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Comment: This rotates camera. OP dosnt want to rotate.

Comment: yeah ... about that, I don't have any idea how to do that :( So I gave this solution that may help others(may be even OP if situation changes). Another thing, I kind of assumed he wanted to avoid manual calculation of transform.rotation. So yeah ... I know this is not a very good solution

Comment: I think your solution is very good solution in most cases. I even up vote it. But the question dosnt allow changing rotation. I have no idea why :)

Comment: how do i post pictures so i can explain my query in a better way

Comment: One line of code and it did the work
`transform.rotation =   (transform.rotation)*Quaternion.Euler(0,0,transform.rotation.z+180);`

Comment: @PiyushDamania awesome! And yes, pictures would help us understand the situation a lot better

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy way,created an empty gameObject rotated it upside down and inserted the second camera in it,still any other solutions are welcome and tips for multiplayer on same phone would also be great help,thanks!

Edit:This does not work.